# Confusion about using PCA in sklearn for image retrieval

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I need to use dimension reduction when doing image retieval ,and I try using `PCA` reduce dim 2048 to 512 in `sklearn`,below is my sample code :

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np 

x = np.random.random((32,2048)) //shape : (batch,dim)
pca = PCA(n_components = dim,copy = True)
pca.fit(x)
```

the code gives error :

```
ValueError: n_components=512 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=32 with svd_solver='full'
```

And if I change the process pre batch by using `pca(x[0])` raise the error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

So if I want to use reduce dimension 2048 to 512 using PCA ? How do I achieve this ? Thanks !

Comment: It might help: https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/principal-component-analysis-for-image-data

Comment: @MithridatestheGreat Sorry , I do not see anything helpful information in this article .Can you provide more explicate guide or solution ? Thanks

Comment: I think you need to read more about basics of PCA. You can't reduce number of dimensions from 2048 to 512 when you have only 32 points. It's already mentioned in the answer. Other than that it would work perfectly fine. By the way, the link that is given in my initial comment is doing exactly the same thing as you want to do.

Comment: @MithridatestheGreat oh,sorry about not describe clearly, what I would like to do is do dim reduction "per feature" . 32 here means batch size not the points , so the desired output should be something like (32,512) , which means these feature should be processed independently,how do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that you cannot have number of component (`n_components`) to keep that is lower than both `n_feature` and `n_samples`. You therefore need to have more sample to perform this transformation. (at least 512)